# Tapestry getting started

Tags: web-frameworks, tapestry

All goes OK until mvn jetty:run which ends with [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.16:run (default-cli) on project newapp: Failure: Address already in use: bind

That is no surprise as I have Tomcat running on 8080 with my own site (that can not be changed). Did mvn indeed install jetty and tries running it? May I configure Jetty to a different port or maybe use Tomcat instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Jetty to use another port by setting the system property **jetty.port**.

The **jetty.port** property can be set in the command line when running Maven:

```
mvn -Djetty.port=9090 jetty:run
```

Or it can be set in the project's pom.xml, as part of the **maven-jetty-plugin** configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>tapestry.execution-mode</name>
                <value>development</value>
            </systemProperty>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>jetty.port</name>
                <value>9090</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In both examples Jetty is configured to listen to port 9090.